# Flutter - How to get position of dragged object relative to a widget

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop, position

I'm building a game where the user can select diferent shapes and drag them to a grid.

The game is working fine right now, but to know where the user is droping the object I am doing the following:

```
Position Y = 

(dragDetails.offset.dy - ((heightOfScreen * sizeOfScrenBeforeGrid) + gridSquareSize)) + scrolledPixels,
```

So in order for this to work, I need to create a Container with a fix height for the content before the grid. Also I need to add a listener in order to know if the user scroll the page.

I would like to achieve the same, but instead of having the sizeOfScrenBeforeGrid and the scrolledPixels, I want to know the position of my dragged object relative to the grid widget where the user drop the object.

I tried to put a listener or a gesture detector in the grid, but it didnt work.

Someone can help me to achieve this?